# rounding a number, NOT necessarily decimel PHP

Tags: php, integer

I have a question.

I am using php to generate a number based on operations that a user has specified

This variable is called

```
$new
```

$new is an integer, I want to be able to round $new to a 12 digit number, regardless of the answer

I was thinking I could use 
round() or ceil()

but I believe these are used for rounding decimel places

---

So, I have an integer stored in $new, when $new is echoed out I want for it to print 12 digits. Whether the number is 60 billion or 0.00000000006

Comment: `sprintf('%10d', $new)`

Comment: _"I want to be able to round $new to a 12 digit number"_ I don't understand that

Comment: I have an integer stored in $new, when $new is echoed out I want for it to print 12 digits. Whether the number is 60 billion or 0.00000000006. So I am asuming the number will need to be rounded somewhere

Comment: Please explain your rounding algorithm. I assume that `1` should be rounded to `100000000000`?

Comment: Let me try and be a bit more plain, I have a textbox which displays an int variable. The textbox can only display 12 digits but the number entered could be a lot more.

Comment: So what should 1 be rounded to? What should 100000000000000 be rounded to?

Comment: this thing i am trying to do will form part of an if statement. That only applies itself to when the .length of a display is more than 12

Comment: if the number is 0.00000000006 should it display like 000000000001 ?

Comment: Yes, 0.000000000006 should become 0.00000000001

Comment: 0.000000006 is not an integer. What is the problem domain here? It sounds like you want **integers** that are "too long" (too many places) to be changed into scientific notation and the mantissa rounded to fit. Is that correct? As an aside, can PHP actually support 64 bit integers (10^18) or is it limited to 32 bit (or even, is everything float internally)? Or do you want general "fitting" of any number (int or float) to N characters?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly

```
function showNumber($input) {
  $show = 12;
  $input = number_format(min($input,str_repeat('9', $show)), ($show-1) - strlen(number_format($input,0,'.','')),'.','');

  return $input;
}

var_dump(showNumber(1));
var_dump(showNumber(0.00000000006));
var_dump(showNumber(100000000000000000000000));
```

gives

```
string(12) "1.0000000000"
string(12) "0.0000000001"
string(12) "999999999999"
```